# Real-time eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, real-time

i'm searching for a plugin or a tool for eclipse that can show me the result of my code in real-time, without always close the application and recompile it to see the changes. I'm not sure i've been clear...
I'm searching for something that constantly compile and run my code to see the results of my editing in real-time. I don't know if exist comething like this, i searched all over the web but i've found nothing. Do you know anything like this?

Sorry for my english but it's not my mother language, thanks.

Comment: I'm looking around for something like this too, you find anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JRebel would be the closest you will get to what you want I think

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, Eclipse already has a mode for that called debug. The button is right next to the play button and looks like a bug, If you run your program in debug mode you can make changes and it will update. it won't allow large changes of code though but smaller changes take effect immediately.

Comment: By smaller changes it is better to say - "only inside method body". Basically you can just add/delete/change statements within a method, nothing else.